# multiple mutate() with pmap?

Tags: r, dplyr, pmap

I have a dataset that is wide for 10 sessions and each session has ID#s for two team members. I want to paste the to ID#s together to form team IDs. I can do this with 10 mutate (one for each team), but am trying to find a way to have 1 mutate inside a map or pmap.

A simple data example with only 2 sessions is

```
df2 <- data.frame( subj = c(1001,1002),
               id1.s1 = c(21, 44), 
               id2.s1 = c(21, 55), 
               id1.s2 = c(23, 44), 
               id2.s2 = c(21, 77))

df2 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(team.s1=paste(id1.s1, id2.s1, sep="-")) %>%
  mutate(team.s2=paste(id1.s2, id2.s2, sep="-")) %>%
  select(grep("subj|team", names(.)))
```

This gives

```
  subj team.s1 team.s2
1 1001   21-21   23-21
2 1002   44-55   44-77
```

Is there a way to make a 3 element list with e1 = 10 team names, e2 = 10 ID#1, e3 = 10 ID#2 and use mutate inside of pmap? OR some other wat that avoids 10 mutate lines?

I could not figure out how to get the data frame name into mutate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution based on [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr)'s `gather` and `spread` functions. The `separate` function is to separate one column based on a pattern.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df1 %>%
  gather(ID_S, Value, -subj) %>%
  separate(ID_S, into = c("ID", "S")) %>%
  group_by(subj, S) %>%
  summarise(Value = paste(Value, collapse = "-")) %>%
  mutate(S = paste0("team.", S)) %>%
  spread(S, Value) %>%
  ungroup()
df2
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
# subj team.s1 team.s2
# * <dbl> <chr>   <chr>  
# 1  1001 21-21   23-21  
# 2  1002 44-55   44-77
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <- data.frame( subj = c(1001,1002),
                   id1.s1 = c(21, 44), 
                   id2.s1 = c(21, 55), 
                   id1.s2 = c(23, 44), 
                   id2.s2 = c(21, 77))
```

Comment: Thanks @www, this seems to be what I asked. I will study each step to understand.

Answer (score 1):

One option could be `split` the data frame based on the column names' suffix, i.e., `s1/s2` or sessions, then for each session paste the columns with `do.call(paste, ...)`:

With `tidyverse` (version 1.2.1):

```
df2 %>% 
    split.default(sub('id[12]\\.(s[0-9]+)', '\\1', names(.))) %>% 
    map_dfc(~do.call(paste, c(sep="-", .)))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  s1    s2    subj 
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 21-21 23-21 1001 
#2 44-55 44-77 1002
```

Comment: Your answer made me realize I wasn't answering OP's question

Comment: You can use `tidyr::unite` programmatically the same way, e.g. `df2 %>% 
    split.default(sub('.*\\.([^.]*)$', '\\1', names(.))) %>% 
    imap_dfc(~unite(.x, !!.y, sep = '-'))`

Comment: @alistaire Good idea!